# How can I display current weather in plain text thanks to simpleweather.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, weather

I'm using the [weather.js](http://weatherjs.com/), I included in my html file necessary imports:

```
<script src="js/current.js"></script>
<script src="js/sugar.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/weather.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/converters.js"></script>
```

and put the html tag to display the weather:

```
<h2 id="weather"><i></i><span class="conditions"></span></h2>
```

Later on I put the javascript:

```
 Weather.getCurrent('Kansas City', function(current) {
        $('#weather .conditions').text(Weather.kelvinToFahrenheit(current.temperature()).toFixed() + '° and ' + current.conditions());
 });
```

(I used [this page](https://github.com/noazark/weather/blob/master/test/index.html) as an example). But it doesn't work, I see empty space over there. Does anyone have any hint for me?

In general, I need only a simple string on my webpage, like: 73degrees, cloudy, so if there's any other api I could use - I will also appreciate any hints

Comment: Please confirm you have a jquery reference.

Comment: ok, I'm a little bit lost - isn't the reference mentioned in my javascript?

Comment: No, you have to add a line like `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>` to your imports. See the [jquery download page](http://jquery.com/download/) to learn about all your options for including jquery libs.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I totally misunderstood your question, yes, I've got current jquery library..

Comment: which one is weatherjs file?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I added it from https://github.com/noazark/weather/blob/master/weather.js and also included it in the html source file, but that didn't help unfortunately, my div is still empty..

Answer (score 2):

It seems that http://openweathermap.org/ API which weather.js uses, has been changed and will no longer work with this javascript library. If you check in your browser network console you can see that the request to openweathermap returns with 512 http code response:

```
HTTP/1.1 512 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 06 May 2015 13:55:46 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=60
```

which is a server error and not on your side.

Comment: Are there any other working JavaScript libraries for weather?